# How can I change the scope/context of a call to a javascript property?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I think it is easiest to explain my question with a simple example.

Imagine there exists a simple Javascript class hierarchy involving the classes Shape and Square where Square 'inherits' from Shape. Also, in this scenario, Shape has a property named 'colour' (an actual property created using Object.defineProperty on the Shape prototype) and a function called 'draw'. Additionally, in this example the Shape class has a member variable called 'alpha' that is initialized in the Shape constructor. Also assume that the Shape constructor is invoked via the Square constructor.

Assume in this scenario that Shape's draw function is defined as:

```
Shape.prototype.draw = function(canvas) {
   alpha = 52;
   // do some stuff
};
```

Then having Square override and call the parent (Shape) draw function is trivial:

```
Square.prototype.draw = function(canvas) {

  // Do some stuff here

  Shape.prototype.draw.call(this, canvas);
};
```

However, I cannot seem to figure out how to do the same for the 'colour' property since I can't work out how to change the scope/context of the call to the setter to the instance of Square (i.e. 'this'). For example, if i try:

```
Object.defineProperty(Square.prototype, "colour", {
    set : function(value) {
        // Do some stuff    
        Shape.prototype.colour = 55;
    }
});
```

Then this will of course fail if Shape's colour setter method attempts to access 'alpha' since 'alpha' is defined in the Square object instance and not in the Shape prototype.
Ideally i would like to be able to do something like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(Square.prototype, "colour", {
    set : function(value) {
        // Do some stuff    

        // Imagine that 'call_set' is a function like call, only for property setters.
        Shape.prototype.colour.call_set(this, 55);

    }
});
```

Unfortunately AFAIK, there is no such JS method like 'call_set'.

Is it possible to somehow call a property getter/setter using an arbitrary scope?

Assume in this example that the implementation of Shape is 'set in stone' and cannot be changed. So an answer such as 'Don't use properties' will unfortunately not solve this problem.

Comment: I should also mention that setting 'alpha' in Shape's prototype is also not an option as I wish to maintain 'alpha' on a 'per instance' basis (i.e. if it were placed in Shape.prototype then it would be shared by all Shape and Shape derived instances).

Comment: Whenever you change the `Square`'s colour, you actually want to change `Shape`'s colour?

Comment: @thefourtheye, when Square is instantiated there is only one 'instance' of the object and so I am actually looking to change the colour of the Square instance when colour is set through Square's property setter. However, I wish to still invoke Shape's colour setter so that in effect, i am overriding the 'colour' property setter method but still invoking the parent (Square) implementation.

Comment: Why to go through such pain, instead of having the `Shape` define `colour` on `Square`?

Comment: I think your abstract example may not be conveying the requirements precisely.  I assume Shape does something when the colour changes which is why you want to call the 'setter'.  There is no neat workaround in JS.  Just define a method on the Shape object setColourAndPaintTheHouse and have that both set the property and do some work.  Property setters shouldnt really have side effects IMO.

Comment: @thefortheye If by "having the Shape define Colour on Square" you mean define the variable and property solely in Square, the reason I would not do this is because this breaks polymorphic behavior which is in fact the whole point of deriving from Shape in this instance :)

Comment: @flueresce I like the spirit of your answer but this comes back to the last paragraph of my question which reads "Assume in this example that the implementation of Shape is 'set in stone' and cannot be changed. So an answer such as 'Don't use properties' will unfortunately not solve this problem.". Also, see the solution which I came up with. It appears that indeed it is possible to do such a thing, it just isn't obvious (at least, not for me).

Comment: @flueresce Oh and just to clarify, you are correct in assuming that Shape is supposed to do something special when colour changes. I had a bit of difficulty in stating my exact problem, i'm glad you were able to read in between the lines :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I found the answer to this and thought that I should post it in case anyone else has the some problem.

So the solution I came up with is this:

```
Object.defineProperty(Square.prototype, "colour", {
    set : function(value) {
        // Do some stuff    
        var parentProp = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Shape.prototype, "colour");
        parentProp.set.call(this, value);
    }
});
```

The key to solving the problem was simply in knowing how to access the 'get' and 'set' methods of the property.
If anyone has any better or more eloquent solutions then please share :)